# show pdf with bytestream in an updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I want to send a pfd in bytestream to the user in an updatepanel, but I can't get it to work.

```
            Print print = new Print();
            byte[] pdfTransport;
            pdfTransport = //get the byte array
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Tpt" + lblTransportNr.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(",", "") + ".pdf");

            Response.BinaryWrite(pdfTransport);
            string value;
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            value = enc.GetString(pdfTransport);
            Response.End();
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Clear();
```

If I use this, it works without an updatepanel in the .aspx page. When I put the page in an updatepanel I get an Parsing error. Does anyone have an idea to avoid this problem or to solve it?
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't send byte streams through an AJAX request, it's just a technology limitation. And UpdatePanel uses asynchronous requests (AJAX).

Comment: Yeah, you can workaround that by using some kind of iframe so page sends a request through it and this is how some file would be prompted for downloading it avoiding full-postbacks...

Answer (score 0):

don't understand what you want.... do you want to see 1. the pdf content in a webpage, or 2. the binary of the pdf in a human readable format ?

if 1. : don't use an update panel... but an iframe to the pdf url

if 2. : don't write to the response, with set the Text property of a label within the updatepanel